# Git authentication not opening VSCode as "other user"

Tags: authentication, github, visual-studio-code

To set the scene: I work in a highly restricted SOE. I can only sign in as a standard user, but have administrative access through "Run as other user" or "Run as administrator".

When trying to setup GitHub access, VSCode running as administrator opens an authentication window in a browser that then wants to re-open VSCode. The issue is, reopening VSCode in this manner only opens as the standard user, not running as administrator. This happens connected to the internet through the work network, and via hotspot.

I am ***NOT*** permitted to sign-in directly as administrator.

My colleague has told me there used to be a way to sign in by copying and pasting a token directly into VSCode, but this appears to no longer be an option.

Is there another way to authenticate GitHub with VSCode, other than the web-based sign-in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this some time ago by getting a Personal Access Token working.

The environment I'm forced to work in made even this difficult, but got there eventually.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).